# Using tabs in asp.net mvc with jquery ui

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, razor

I am trying to create tabs in my mvc application using jquery ui.

I tried the following code:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tabs').tabs();
});
</script>
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Exploded pie slice</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Normal pie chart</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">@(Html.Partial("PartialView1"))</div>
<div id="tabs-2">@(Html.Partial("PartialView2"))</div>
</div>
```

I saw something like the above code in jquery ui demo. Please advice me what I'm missing in my code because I only get two links instead of tabs and my two partial view pages are displayed in the index page.

Thanks,
Anandaraj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't included the jQuery UI CSS file.

Either use the [default skin](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css), or [pick one, or even build your own](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

Bear in mind that you'll need all the images too, so follow my second link to download the whole theme (either an existing one or one you have built).